# ViewModel and LiveData Observer Not Invoking

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

**`Observer`** not calling in Second Fragment. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Fragment1**

```
   viewModel.productData(model) 
   findNavController().navigate(R.id.actionProductListToDetails)
```

**`ViewModel`** class

```
val productData = MutableLiveData<ModelProductSubItem>()
    fun productData(data: ModelProductSubItem) {
        productData.value = data
    }
```

**Fragment2**

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProductSubListItemViewModel::class.java)
        viewModel.productData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer{ it ->

           println("Product_Name"+it.product_name) // Not invoking
        })
```

Tried with

```
viewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProductSubListItemViewModel::class.java)
        } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
 })
```

**`FYI`**

I have same **`ViewModelProvider`**

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is there may be two ViewModelProvider(this), each using "this" on a different fragment. If you have two providers, then there are two separate models that do not share their triggers.

That's why, when you call ViewModelProvider you call the activity which holds the fragments as the single source:

```
viewmodel = activity?.run {
    ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SomeViewModel::class.java)
} ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")
```

Although with the newer version of ViewModel and fragment-ktx artifact this is not neccesary, I would recommend using this [latest version](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel).

Comment: I have same ViewModelProvider

Comment: Notice that you have to instantiate viewmodel with acitivity in Fragment 1 and Fragment 2.

Comment: instantiate viewmodel with acitivity in Fragment 1 and Fragment 2. ~ Yes yes

Answer (score 0):

Most likely what's happening is that, despite your FYI comment, you are actually instantiating different ViewModels for each context. If you want to share the same instance of an Activity ViewModel among multiple Fragments, then each fragment should get the shared ViewModel like this:

```
new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SomeViewModel.class)
```

Instead of

```
new ViewModelProvider(this)).get(SomeViewModel.class)
```

If you are using Kotlin extensions (KTX) I believe you should do this:

```
val viewModel by activityViewModels<SomeViewModel>()
```

Instead of

```
val viewModel by viewModels<SomeViewModel>()
```

Comment: `ViewModelProviders.of` deprecated

Comment: tried with `ViewModelProvider(let {activity}!!).get(`

Comment: I can see that the API has changed a little bit since I last used it, but the idea seems to be the same: you have to make sure that the owner of the viewmodel you are trying to get is not the fragment itself, but the parent activity. In Java is done like this `new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);`